# how to left join/merge in R based on 2 criteria: numerical match and date-range evaluation

Tags: r, dplyr, merge, left-join

I have two data frames: summary and hauled. I want to create a new column in hauled that returns the values from summary$rfp_id based on 2 matching criteria:

1. Match summary$company_id with hauled$company_id
2. Compare hauled$trans_date with summary$start_date and summary$end_date and return whichever rfp_id most closely matches based on the below explanation of possible outcomes.

summary dataframe:

| rfp_id | start_date | end_date | company_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 12/30/2022 | 2/28/2023 | 7 |
| 2 | 4/1/2022 | 6/30/2022 | 8 |
| 3 | 7/1/2022 | 8/30/2022 | 8 |
| 4 | 1/16/2022 | 1/16/2023 | 9 |
| 5 | 1/1/2023 | 2/6/2023 | 9 |

hauled dataframe (rfp_id = desired result):

| trans# | company_id | trans_date | rfp_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11 | 7 | 1/14/2023 | 1 |
| 12 | 8 | 7/2/2022 | 3 |
| 13 | 8 | 3/20/2022 | 2 |
| 14 | 8 | 9/1/2022 | 3 |
| 15 | 9 | 1/15/2023 | 5 |

The first example (trans# = 11) returns rfp_id = 1 since company 7 only appears once in summary and hauled$trans_date of 1/14/2023 falls between the start/end dates of 12/30/2022 and 2/28/2023.

The second example (trans# = 12)returns rfp_id = 3 since the trans_date of 7/2/2022 falls between 7/1/2022-8/30/2022 (and not between 4/1/2022-6/30/2022).

The third example (trans# = 13 )returns rfp_id = 2 because the trans_date of 3/20/2022 falls outside both start/end date ranges, however it is closest to the start_date of 4/1/2022

The fourth example (trans# = 14 )returns rfp_id = 3 because the trans_date of 9/1/2022 falls outside both start/end date ranges, however it is closest to the end_date of 8/30/2022.

The fifth example (trans# = 15) returns rfp_id = 5 because when a trans_date falls between 2 or more start/end date ranges then the rfp_id to return is whichever has the latest end_date

I don't have a strong background in R. Most of what I have tried has been from chatgpt. The code it spits out continuously throws off a 'many-to-many' error when executed.

Comment: why is it in the third example, you use the one closest to the start, and in the second, it's the closest one to the end? Doesn't make a lot of sense

Comment: @Mark - I assume because in the third example it's before both date ranges, and in the second it's after them i.e. it should be the closest limit (start or finish) of either range, but I agree it's not well defined.

Comment: I've added an answer with a fairly brutish approach - I think it should be possible as a join but I don't know how to prioritise multiple matching criteria. `left_join()` and `join_by()` can use `company_id == company_id` and `between(trans_date, start_date, end_date)` but then I come unstuck for how to join the others - possibly multiple joins would be needed?

Comment: @PaulStaffordAllen thanks for the clarification! `join_by()` can do rudimentary calculations but nothing like the type that OP is asking for. Something like what you did is a good approach +1

Comment: thanks very much for the code @Paul Stafford Allen. When I C&P what you provided into a new r script it works perfectly. When I C&P it into my actual working script I get the below error Any ideas??
Error in `pmap()`:
ℹ In index: 1.
Caused by error in `.f()`:
! unused arguments....
Backtrace:
 1. base::unlist(...)
 2. purrr::pmap(...)
 3. purrr:::pmap_("list", .l, .f, ..., .progress = .progress)
 6. purrr:::call_with_cleanup(...)

Comment: Check the arguments in the anonymous function match the column names in your dataset - I amended them.  You may need to wrap `trans#` in back ticks: `\`trans#\``

Answer (score 3):

OK, this works but it's early here and I'm one hundred percent sure there is a MUCH more elegant and less laborious approach to this, I'm just not seeing it (yet).  Maybe after coffee:

```
library(tidyverse)
# you can just load the required packages when you streamline this code, but I'm lazy.

# Preparing data from OP
summary_df <- tribble(
  ~rfp_id,  ~start_date,    ~end_date,  ~company_id,
  1,    "12/30/2022",   "2/28/2023",    7,
  2,    "4/1/2022", "6/30/2022",    8,
  3,    "7/1/2022", "8/30/2022",    8,
  4,    "1/16/2022",    "1/16/2023",    9,
  5,    "1/1/2023", "2/6/2023", 9
)

summary_df <- summary_df |> mutate(across(ends_with("_date"), ~ as.Date(.x, format = "%m/%d/%Y")))

hauled_df <- tribble( # note I used trans_no instead of trans# to avoid having to enclose it in back ticks each time.
  ~trans_no,    ~company_id,    ~trans_date,
  11,   7,  "1/14/2023",
  12,   8,  "7/2/2022",
  13,   8,  "3/20/2022",
  14,   8,  "9/1/2022",
  15,   9,  "1/15/2023",
)

hauled_df$trans_date <- as.Date(hauled_df$trans_date, format = "%m/%d/%Y")
```

I have made the assumption that there will ALWAYS be at least one match of company-id - if that's wrong, add a test here.
I also assumed that if outside of all ranges, you wanted the nearest range border (start OR finish).

```
hauled_df$rfp_id <- unlist(pmap(.l = hauled_df,
                             .f = \(trans_no,   company_id, trans_date) {
                               com_id = company_id
                               summary_df |>
                                 filter(company_id == com_id) |>
                                 mutate(score = case_when(
                                   trans_date >= start_date & trans_date <= end_date ~ 0,
                                   trans_date < start_date ~ as.integer(start_date - trans_date),
                                   .default = as.integer(trans_date - end_date)
                                 )) |>
                                 filter(score == min(score)) |>
                                 filter(end_date == max(end_date)) |>
                                 select(rfp_id)
                             }
))
```

output:

```
> hauled_df
# A tibble: 5 × 4
  trans_no company_id trans_date rfp_id
     <dbl>      <dbl> <date>      <dbl>
1       11          7 2023-01-14      1
2       12          8 2022-07-02      3
3       13          8 2022-03-20      2
4       14          8 2022-09-01      3
5       15          9 2023-01-15      5
```

Explanation:

```
pmap(.l = hauled_df,
```

`pmap` is parallel map - basically it applies the function to each row of hauled df, feeding that row's values for `trans_no, company_id, trans_date` into the function:

```
.f = \(trans_no, company_id, trans_date) {
     com_id = company_id # almost certainly unnecessary
     summary_df |>
     filter(company_id == com_id) |>
```

take a copy of the `summary_df` and filter out all the rows without matching company IDs.
We're then going to score each remaining row - lower is better/higher priority.
Inside the date range scores 0.  Outside it scores x where x is the number of days before or after the edge of the range.

```
     mutate(score = case_when(
     trans_date >= start_date & trans_date <= end_date ~ 0, # inside the date range
     trans_date < start_date ~ as.integer(start_date - trans_date), # before the date range
     .default = as.integer(trans_date - end_date) # after the date range
                                 )) |>
```

We then need to firstly take the best (lowest) `score`, then do any tie breaks on the latest `end_date` and extract the `rfp_id` from the one remaining row:

```
                                 filter(score == min(score)) |>
                                 filter(end_date == max(end_date)) |>
                                 select(rfp_id)
                             }
```

Comment: thanks very much for the code Paul. When I C&P what you provided into a new r script it works perfectly. When I C&P it into my actual working script I get this error:

Comment: @MalcMalcMalc it helps to post the error